# Can't understand the return of promise in koa and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, koa

The code in `mysql.js` file

```
let query = function( sql, values ) {
return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            reject( err )
        } else {
            connection.query(sql, values, ( err, rows) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err )
                } else {
                    resolve( rows )
                }
                connection.release()
            })
        }
    })
  })
}

let optUser = function (value) {
  let _sql = "sql command"
  return query(_sql, value)
}
```

The call code is following

```
let result = mysqlModel.optUser([s,d]).then()
```

Here the `result` is null or not null, and I don't understand this, here are my questions

1. If I use `select` command, such as `let _sql = "select * from table where key1=? and key2=?"`, if the `result`is null, that means have no record, if the `result` is not null, it will return the corresponding user data, am I right?
2. What's the return in `update`, `delete`, `insert`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you will get `null` if query doesn't returns anything and if it does it will give the `data`
2. for update, delete, insert you will get `json` which consist of certain keys like `changedRows`, `affectedRows`. A 'insert' query will give you the insertId for that row. Basically you will get a confirmation that your operation is successfully executed.

`connection.query(sql, values, ( err, results, fields) => {
  if ( err ) {
    reject( err )
  } else {
    resolve( rows )
  }
 connection.release()
})`

Comment: Why do you add `fields` here?

Comment: In the fields variable you will get the fields affected by the write queries. for eg: In when insert you will get the inserted fields, or when delete you will get the deleted field.

Answer (score 0):

This `let result = mysqlModel.optUser([s,d]).then()` will not set the correct data to your result variable. It will just return a pending promise. The data can only be received once the promise is resolved. The correct way to call a promise is this :

```
mysqlModel.optUser([s, d])
.then(function (data) {
    // Your data will be present here. You can check for null here.
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    // This is called if the query encounters some error. 
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)